# How can I convert multi text string to table

Tags: php, html

I have a string that contains multiple lines. how can I convert it into tables where in each td value is every word of each line.

example of the string.

Eth1/1        VPC_PEER_KEEPALIVE connected routed    full    1000    1000base-T

Eth1/2        VPC_PEER_KEEPALIVE connected routed    full    1000    1000base-T

expected table outcome:

Eth1/1 | VPC_PEER_KEEPALIVE | connected | routed | full | 1000 | 1000base-T

Eth1/2 | VPC_PEER_KEEPALIVE | connected | routed | full | 1000 | 1000base-T

Comment: Can you share your string? Is it the example one?

Comment: That string is just an example

Comment: do you need to solve the query in js or php

Comment: php sir if possible thanks guys

Comment: I have added the changes just check and say me

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    $str = "Eth1/1 VPC_PEER_KEEPALIVE connected routed full 1000 1000base-T
Eth1/2 VPC_PEER_KEEPALIVE connected routed full 1000 1000base-T";
// echo $str;

$v1 = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
foreach ($v1 as $key => $value) {
    $v2 = explode(" ", $value);
    echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($v2 as $key2 => $value2) {
            echo "<td>" .$value2 ."</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: good to hear...keep on coding

Answer (score 0):

This JS code will work-

```js
var string = "Eth1/1 VPC_PEER_KEEPALIVE connected routed full 1000 1000base-T"; //Whatever your string is
string = string.split(" ");
var table = "<table id='table' border='1px'><tr>";
for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  table += "<td>" + string[i] + "</td>";
}
table += "</tr></table>";
document.write(table); //Whatever you want do with your table
```

Comment: yes this works if its a single line text. what if the entire string is composed of multiple lines like in the example?

Comment: I see ok I will edit the code